# How to set expiry date for a cookie in Angular 2?

Tags: cookies, angular

How to add expiry date to Angular 2 cookie. I am trying with Angular 2.0.0-beta.15. When i try to add options like below:

```
var expireDate = new Date (new Date().getTime() + (1000 * data.expires_in));

this._cookieService.put('token', this.token, {expires: expireDate});
```

above code throwing error like "[ts] Argument of type '{ expires: Date; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CookieOptionsArgs'.

> Property 'path' is missing in type '{ expires: Date; }'. (local var)
>   expireDate: Date"

I can see on https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-cookie to override default options globally. I doubt if this is the method to add expiry date to cookie? Can somebody help me to understand more on this?

Comment: i think all parameters are mandatory. when i added all parameters error is gone. isnt possible to add just one parameter to cookie?

Comment: I'd suggest to use Angular 2 rc3, and then take the 1.2.x version of the angular2-cookie `Please use 1.1.x versions for angular2 beta, 1.2.x versions are for release candidates.`

Answer (score 2):

I have used this library with success: https://github.com/BCJTI/ng2-cookies. Use it like below with setting expiry date:

1. Include the lib:

   import {Cookie} from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';
2. Set a cookie with expiry date of 365 days:

   Cookie.setCookie("cookie-key", "cookie-value", 365);

Answer (score 2):

A little bit late but Should be something like this

```
let key = 'testCookieKey'; 
let value = 'testCookieValue';
let opts: CookieOptionsArgs = {
    expires: new Date('2030-07-19')
};
cookieService.put(key, value, opts);
```

Hope that

Comment: where do you immport CookieOptionsArgs from ?

Comment: you need to install   angular2-cookie npm    after that   import { CookieService, CookieOptionsArgs } from 'angular2-cookie/core';

Answer (score 1):

For Expiry date parameter in set cookies the value should be **seconds to days** calculation.

i.e. 2 min = (2/1440)

//use for 2 minutes....

> auth-cookies.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies/ng2-cookies';

@Injectable()
export class AuthCookie {
    constructor() { }

    getAuth(): string {
        return Cookie.get('id_token');
    }

    setAuth(value: string): void {
        //0.0138889=20 minuts 
        //this accept day not minuts
        //use for 20 minuts
        Cookie.set('cookie_token', value, 0.0138889);
        //use for 2 minuts
     //  Cookie.set('cookie_token', value,0.00138889)
    }

    deleteAuth(): void {
        Cookie.delete('id_token');
    }
}
```

i post it too late but hope this will be useful.